# Is there a key in the keyboard that is the opposite of an escape key?

Tags: windows, keyboard

When you press the escape key, for example, in a YouTube video, it comes out. I recently saw someone press a button to put it in a video and not the other way around as opposed to esacpe, in the keyboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean putting the video full screen you just need to press the 'f' key. But there is no generic key that allows you to do something like this, it depends on the application.